# Python filter list of dictionaries

Tags: python

Newbie here please be gentle:

I have a HAR file which I want to filter:

```
{'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty', 'Host': 'ex.ex.com', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Referer': 'https://ex.ex.com/wtp', 'Accept-Language': 'en-GB', 'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors', 'Accept': '*/*', 'x-device-user-agent': 'vendor=ex Group | applicationType=ex | platform=WTP | version=0.3923.0+6a372d26', 'cst': '6bb4001ccf2474747ed54ff6de03f02d8714141d635bebd7497ce959b037468b01112', 'ADRUM': 'isAjax:true', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36', 'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-orexin', 'ex-account-id': 'KY7KR', 'Cookie': 'optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1583357659438r0.7157397828419743; AMCVS_434717FE52A6476F0A490D4C%40AdobeOrg=1; s_ecid=MCMID%7C20943112109103996344566288029049590877; _ga=GA1.2.2101991366.1583357668; _gid=GA1.2.659170049.1583357668; _gat=1; _gcl_au=1.1.578614386.1583357681; _gat_UA-53269626-3=1; ACCESS-TOKEN=eyJraWQiOiJDQVE4QU1JSUJDZ0tDQVFFQXFKdiIsInR5cCI6IkNMSUVOVF9BQ0NFU1MiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInppcCI6IkdaSVAifQ.H4sIAAAAAAAAAFXOvQrCMBQF4He5c4fc5ucm3cRFcRBaFxGHJrkpBY1iWxDEdzcugpzt48A5L-hDuC15nqA5we5IuxbOFYTLyHneRmgABdaona2hgmXiR-6vXHizatujtVIUXneHIsZ7JQSGkGpF33DUKiUTWcgk6mgJVUk0Unv2kZSjwE47LyQpY71AxO_I2M_QoLZSajKWCkzlHHRjHi7cjUPe59LKPv23-Hn_gbP0_gAcCGQQ2gAAAA.Sc0r41f8_pgWw1jJa0CF0JW6Dl0cQcJlzCL-TAPmv80Zx4JtFqJhtRJGWF_tJF0mKzPhGC6hNM4PP9LSnXPjnmjNnLkcvgJ_oen42xWorSr64ICSde_MHVV13U6eS1RKvvLhHiZzK1TqihZiZaeOkGnbTaouPTuupIrRi8Rbyf52IyicB8JMMvSjYBILOk57rCDdieIRVDtrCM4hzq_a3e_tiJyw4-2k2xU2rbf8dJT9LZw9LqMTFPFsBoYFWrqnAWd99TuKRLP2CMe2ZEHv1EX5bYV7dtqJ0yvxC196AiVFiZNkk9nQ7y1LNrVzOXUx1h6aAZy3O_NuZefBft5ORA; CST=6bb4001ccf2474747ed54ff6de03f02d8714141d635bebd7497ce959b037468b01112; ID=TD=DB400FA09853FBF32BD51785C67BDB2F2EEB2D75:CS=2:A=1; ex-ENVIRONMENT=PROD; REFRESH-TOKEN=eyJraWQiOiJDQVE4QU1JSUJDZ0tDQVFFQXFKdiIsInR5cCI6IkNMSUVOVF9SRUZSRVNIIiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYiLCJ6aXAiOiJHWklQIn0.H4sIAAAAAAAAAFXOPwvCMBAF8O-S2SGXf3fpJi46Ca2LY5NcSqAGsRUE8bub4iRv-_F4d28R58J1PSXRCZCgwHpSYieeCz_qeOPGx33fX4m0bHwYLk1cCEZKiDErg1s4WZOzSyx1lioRgmlJTtvAIaHxGNlbH6RG4yhIANiOlHEVHVjS2qIjbLAsbX4odZp5KFM919aqIf-3-HX_QXuCCD9fCHeVyMUAAAA.Lh_kFotiEJ7UxHygQ-Xfl95lgoVWj_KxCetoEXj9_ARBo1GEWu8MAgDKHD25Nobb_4gh2rftzkfUeL8p043i_EfIL3ZZGT9xAhevfexRCl-cSvbc6yC7NisgTo_eJznZeWNZ-fvRT__JhYmVXsRL4X6_M6l5exXXIFUEzNN19s4t44KrSqctkvRpa0OFoKX3_9znpL86sJ3ASyHv2LkFgzNYp5gHanaltq0cER-EPLwmODSW8pQbN5kkFbywr0QIrx_B-V2vZWDsZuXcf6CshR2gNk8cRN_9VWyr7QAVPIWPA277xNXFtHBFWR1qz-fDOVjdI9PTUTmOHlW_D6ywLA; callerReqId=924329aab8479cb7; client_id=a20fa8511e2a302574dddc5533444d0b; defaultexingPlatform=PUREex; deviceOs=Other; deviceType=Desktop; exitPath=uk; exitUrl=https://www.ex.com/uk; preferredAccountId=KY7KR; sessionOpen=true; AMCV_434717FE52A6476F0A490D4C%40AdobeOrg=-330454231%7CMCIDTS%7C18326%7CMCMID%7C20943112109103996344566288029049590877%7CMCAAMLH-1583962505%7C6%7CMCAAMB-1583962505%7C6G1ynYcLPuiQxYZrsz_pkqfLG9yMXBpb2zX5dvJdYQJzPXImdj0y%7CMCOPTOUT-1583364905s%7CNONE%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CMCSYNCSOP%7C411-18333%7CvVersion%7C3.1.2%7CMCCIDH%7C-1029498915; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; s_cc=true; cpaEnabled=true; AAMC_exgroup_0=REGION%7C6; aamoptsegs=aam%3D10776225%2Caam%3D10776328%2Caam%3D10873328%2Caam%3D10873753%2Caam%3D10554416%2Caam%3D10800273%2Caam%3D10800207%2Caam%3D12237189%2Caam%3D14258131%2Caam%3D16895981%2Caam%3D11348465%2Caam%3D17467451; linkedinexcl=seg%3D10554416; aam_uuid=11663433031890538693630294073720269154; ADRUM=s=1583357709526&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ex.com%2Fuk%2Fmyex%2Fdashboard%3F0; X-SECURITY-TOKEN=42394ab3995a5b2adde7ddcdd3a0d45965256cbf61a1e76a25f061e0f8c6c8c301112; session_start_time=1583357712883; wtp:session=%7B%22authenticated%22%3A%7B%22authenticator%22%3A%22authenticator%3Aplatform%22%2C%22cst%22%3A%226bb4001ccf2474747ed54ff6de03f02d8714141d635bebd7497ce959b037468b01112%22%2C%22xst%22%3A%2242394ab3995a5b2adde7ddcdd3a0d45965256cbf61a1e76a25f061e0f8c6c8c301112%22%7D%7D; lang=en-GB', 'x-security-token': '42394ab3995a5b2adde7ddcdd3a0d45965256cbf61a1e76a25f061e0f8c6c8c301112', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'}
{'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty', 'Host': 'ex.ex.com', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Referer': 'https://ex.ex.com/wtp', 'Accept-Language': 'en-GB', 'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors', 'Accept': '*/*', 'x-device-user-agent': 'vendor=ex Group | applicationType=ex | platform=WTP | version=0.3923.0+6a372d26', 'cst': '6bb4001ccf2474747ed54ff6de03f02d8714141d635bebd7497ce959b037468b01112', 'ADRUM': 'isAjax:true', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36', 'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-orexin', 'ex-account-id': 'KY7KR', 'Cookie': 'optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1583357659438r0.7157397828419743; AMCVS_434717FE52A6476F0A490D4C%40AdobeOrg=1; s_ecid=MCMID%7C20943112109103996344566288029049590877; _ga=GA1.2.2101991366.1583357668; _gid=GA1.2.659170049.1583357668; _gat=1; _gcl_au=1.1.578614386.1583357681; _gat_UA-53269626-3=1; ACCESS-TOKEN=eyJraWQiOiJDQVE4QU1JSUJDZ0tDQVFFQXFKdiIsInR5cCI6IkNMSUVOVF9BQ0NFU1MiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInppcCI6IkdaSVAifQ.H4sIAAAAAAAAAFXOvQrCMBQF4He5c4fc5ucm3cRFcRBaFxGHJrkpBY1iWxDEdzcugpzt48A5L-hDuC15nqA5we5IuxbOFYTLyHneRmgABdaona2hgmXiR-6vXHizatujtVIUXneHIsZ7JQSGkGpF33DUKiUTWcgk6mgJVUk0Unv2kZSjwE47LyQpY71AxO_I2M_QoLZSajKWCkzlHHRjHi7cjUPe59LKPv23-Hn_gbP0_gAcCGQQ2gAAAA.Sc0r41f8_pgWw1jJa0CF0JW6Dl0cQcJlzCL-TAPmv80Zx4JtFqJhtRJGWF_tJF0mKzPhGC6hNM4PP9LSnXPjnmjNnLkcvgJ_oen42xWorSr64ICSde_MHVV13U6eS1RKvvLhHiZzK1TqihZiZaeOkGnbTaouPTuupIrRi8Rbyf52IyicB8JMMvSjYBILOk57rCDdieIRVDtrCM4hzq_a3e_tiJyw4-2k2xU2rbf8dJT9LZw9LqMTFPFsBoYFWrqnAWd99TuKRLP2CMe2ZEHv1EX5bYV7dtqJ0yvxC196AiVFiZNkk9nQ7y1LNrVzOXUx1h6aAZy3O_NuZefBft5ORA; CST=6bb4001ccf2474747ed54ff6de03f02d8714141d635bebd7497ce959b037468b01112; ID=TD=DB400FA09853FBF32BD51785C67BDB2F2EEB2D75:CS=2:A=1; ex-ENVIRONMENT=PROD; REFRESH-TOKEN=eyJraWQiOiJDQVE4QU1JSUJDZ0tDQVFFQXFKdiIsInR5cCI6IkNMSUVOVF9SRUZSRVNIIiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYiLCJ6aXAiOiJHWklQIn0.H4sIAAAAAAAAAFXOPwvCMBAF8O-S2SGXf3fpJi46Ca2LY5NcSqAGsRUE8bub4iRv-_F4d28R58J1PSXRCZCgwHpSYieeCz_qeOPGx33fX4m0bHwYLk1cCEZKiDErg1s4WZOzSyx1lioRgmlJTtvAIaHxGNlbH6RG4yhIANiOlHEVHVjS2qIjbLAsbX4odZp5KFM919aqIf-3-HX_QXuCCD9fCHeVyMUAAAA.Lh_kFotiEJ7UxHygQ-Xfl95lgoVWj_KxCetoEXj9_ARBo1GEWu8MAgDKHD25Nobb_4gh2rftzkfUeL8p043i_EfIL3ZZGT9xAhevfexRCl-cSvbc6yC7NisgTo_eJznZeWNZ-fvRT__JhYmVXsRL4X6_M6l5exXXIFUEzNN19s4t44KrSqctkvRpa0OFoKX3_9znpL86sJ3ASyHv2LkFgzNYp5gHanaltq0cER-EPLwmODSW8pQbN5kkFbywr0QIrx_B-V2vZWDsZuXcf6CshR2gNk8cRN_9VWyr7QAVPIWPA277xNXFtHBFWR1qz-fDOVjdI9PTUTmOHlW_D6ywLA; callerReqId=924329aab8479cb7; client_id=a20fa8511e2a302574dddc5533444d0b; defaultexingPlatform=PUREex; deviceOs=Other; deviceType=Desktop; exitPath=uk; exitUrl=https://www.ex.com/uk; preferredAccountId=KY7KR; sessionOpen=true; AMCV_434717FE52A6476F0A490D4C%40AdobeOrg=-330454231%7CMCIDTS%7C18326%7CMCMID%7C20943112109103996344566288029049590877%7CMCAAMLH-1583962505%7C6%7CMCAAMB-1583962505%7C6G1ynYcLPuiQxYZrsz_pkqfLG9yMXBpb2zX5dvJdYQJzPXImdj0y%7CMCOPTOUT-1583364905s%7CNONE%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CMCSYNCSOP%7C411-18333%7CvVersion%7C3.1.2%7CMCCIDH%7C-1029498915; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; s_cc=true; cpaEnabled=true; AAMC_exgroup_0=REGION%7C6; aamoptsegs=aam%3D10776225%2Caam%3D10776328%2Caam%3D10873328%2Caam%3D10873753%2Caam%3D10554416%2Caam%3D10800273%2Caam%3D10800207%2Caam%3D12237189%2Caam%3D14258131%2Caam%3D16895981%2Caam%3D11348465%2Caam%3D17467451; linkedinexcl=seg%3D10554416; aam_uuid=11663433031890538693630294073720269154; ADRUM=s=1583357709526&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ex.com%2Fuk%2Fmyex%2Fdashboard%3F0; X-SECURITY-TOKEN=42394ab3995a5b2adde7ddcdd3a0d45965256cbf61a1e76a25f061e0f8c6c8c301112; session_start_time=1583357712883; wtp:session=%7B%22authenticated%22%3A%7B%22authenticator%22%3A%22authenticator%3Aplatform%22%2C%22cst%22%3A%226bb4001ccf2474747ed54ff6de03f02d8714141d635bebd7497ce959b037468b01112%22%2C%22xst%22%3A%2242394ab3995a5b2adde7ddcdd3a0d45965256cbf61a1e76a25f061e0f8c6c8c301112%22%7D%7D; lang=en-GB', 'x-security-token': '42394ab3995a5b2adde7ddcdd3a0d45965256cbf61a1e76a25f061e0f8c6c8c301112', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'}
```

I want to extract the cst and x-security-token values and save them to two seperate variables. How do I go about doing that??

Here is my code so far:

```
proxy.har  # returns a
for ent in proxy.har['log']['entries']:
    _url = ent['request']['headers']
    _response = ent['response']
    #print(ent['request']['headers'])
    headers = {e['name']: e['value'] for e in ent['request']['headers']}
    print(headers)
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No error. I want to filter out the cst and x-security-token from the HAR file. how do I do that?

Comment: Can't you just access them like you are accessing the rest of the dictionary values ie `ent['cst']`  etc

Comment: I get keyerror when trying that

Comment: ahhh! so there is an error! You are probably just not at the right level in the dictionary or maybe not even looking at a dictionary anymore if you are looping through keys. can you print the dictionary where you are trying to access the 'cst' key and see where in the dictionary you are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
d = {'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty', 'Host': 'ex.ex.com', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Referer': 'https://ex.ex.com/wtp', 'Accept-Language': 'en-GB', 'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors', 'Accept': '*/*', 'x-device-user-agent': 'vendor=ex Group | applicationType=ex | platform=WTP | version=0.3923.0+6a372d26', 'cst': '6bb4001ccf2474747ed54ff6de03f02d8714141d635bebd7497ce959b037468b01112', 'ADRUM': 'isAjax:true', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36', 'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-orexin', 'ex-account-id': 'KY7KR', 'Cookie': 'optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1583357659438r0.7157397828419743; AMCVS_434717FE52A6476F0A490D4C%40AdobeOrg=1; s_ecid=MCMID%7C20943112109103996344566288029049590877; _ga=GA1.2.2101991366.1583357668; _gid=GA1.2.659170049.1583357668; _gat=1; _gcl_au=1.1.578614386.1583357681; _gat_UA-53269626-3=1; ACCESS-TOKEN=eyJraWQiOiJDQVE4QU1JSUJDZ0tDQVFFQXFKdiIsInR5cCI6IkNMSUVOVF9BQ0NFU1MiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInppcCI6IkdaSVAifQ.H4sIAAAAAAAAAFXOvQrCMBQF4He5c4fc5ucm3cRFcRBaFxGHJrkpBY1iWxDEdzcugpzt48A5L-hDuC15nqA5we5IuxbOFYTLyHneRmgABdaona2hgmXiR-6vXHizatujtVIUXneHIsZ7JQSGkGpF33DUKiUTWcgk6mgJVUk0Unv2kZSjwE47LyQpY71AxO_I2M_QoLZSajKWCkzlHHRjHi7cjUPe59LKPv23-Hn_gbP0_gAcCGQQ2gAAAA.Sc0r41f8_pgWw1jJa0CF0JW6Dl0cQcJlzCL-TAPmv80Zx4JtFqJhtRJGWF_tJF0mKzPhGC6hNM4PP9LSnXPjnmjNnLkcvgJ_oen42xWorSr64ICSde_MHVV13U6eS1RKvvLhHiZzK1TqihZiZaeOkGnbTaouPTuupIrRi8Rbyf52IyicB8JMMvSjYBILOk57rCDdieIRVDtrCM4hzq_a3e_tiJyw4-2k2xU2rbf8dJT9LZw9LqMTFPFsBoYFWrqnAWd99TuKRLP2CMe2ZEHv1EX5bYV7dtqJ0yvxC196AiVFiZNkk9nQ7y1LNrVzOXUx1h6aAZy3O_NuZefBft5ORA; CST=6bb4001ccf2474747ed54ff6de03f02d8714141d635bebd7497ce959b037468b01112; ID=TD=DB400FA09853FBF32BD51785C67BDB2F2EEB2D75:CS=2:A=1; ex-ENVIRONMENT=PROD; REFRESH-TOKEN=eyJraWQiOiJDQVE4QU1JSUJDZ0tDQVFFQXFKdiIsInR5cCI6IkNMSUVOVF9SRUZSRVNIIiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYiLCJ6aXAiOiJHWklQIn0.H4sIAAAAAAAAAFXOPwvCMBAF8O-S2SGXf3fpJi46Ca2LY5NcSqAGsRUE8bub4iRv-_F4d28R58J1PSXRCZCgwHpSYieeCz_qeOPGx33fX4m0bHwYLk1cCEZKiDErg1s4WZOzSyx1lioRgmlJTtvAIaHxGNlbH6RG4yhIANiOlHEVHVjS2qIjbLAsbX4odZp5KFM919aqIf-3-HX_QXuCCD9fCHeVyMUAAAA.Lh_kFotiEJ7UxHygQ-Xfl95lgoVWj_KxCetoEXj9_ARBo1GEWu8MAgDKHD25Nobb_4gh2rftzkfUeL8p043i_EfIL3ZZGT9xAhevfexRCl-cSvbc6yC7NisgTo_eJznZeWNZ-fvRT__JhYmVXsRL4X6_M6l5exXXIFUEzNN19s4t44KrSqctkvRpa0OFoKX3_9znpL86sJ3ASyHv2LkFgzNYp5gHanaltq0cER-EPLwmODSW8pQbN5kkFbywr0QIrx_B-V2vZWDsZuXcf6CshR2gNk8cRN_9VWyr7QAVPIWPA277xNXFtHBFWR1qz-fDOVjdI9PTUTmOHlW_D6ywLA; callerReqId=924329aab8479cb7; client_id=a20fa8511e2a302574dddc5533444d0b; defaultexingPlatform=PUREex; deviceOs=Other; deviceType=Desktop; exitPath=uk; exitUrl=https://www.ex.com/uk; preferredAccountId=KY7KR; sessionOpen=true; AMCV_434717FE52A6476F0A490D4C%40AdobeOrg=-330454231%7CMCIDTS%7C18326%7CMCMID%7C20943112109103996344566288029049590877%7CMCAAMLH-1583962505%7C6%7CMCAAMB-1583962505%7C6G1ynYcLPuiQxYZrsz_pkqfLG9yMXBpb2zX5dvJdYQJzPXImdj0y%7CMCOPTOUT-1583364905s%7CNONE%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CMCSYNCSOP%7C411-18333%7CvVersion%7C3.1.2%7CMCCIDH%7C-1029498915; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; s_cc=true; cpaEnabled=true; AAMC_exgroup_0=REGION%7C6; aamoptsegs=aam%3D10776225%2Caam%3D10776328%2Caam%3D10873328%2Caam%3D10873753%2Caam%3D10554416%2Caam%3D10800273%2Caam%3D10800207%2Caam%3D12237189%2Caam%3D14258131%2Caam%3D16895981%2Caam%3D11348465%2Caam%3D17467451; linkedinexcl=seg%3D10554416; aam_uuid=11663433031890538693630294073720269154; ADRUM=s=1583357709526&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ex.com%2Fuk%2Fmyex%2Fdashboard%3F0; X-SECURITY-TOKEN=42394ab3995a5b2adde7ddcdd3a0d45965256cbf61a1e76a25f061e0f8c6c8c301112; session_start_time=1583357712883; wtp:session=%7B%22authenticated%22%3A%7B%22authenticator%22%3A%22authenticator%3Aplatform%22%2C%22cst%22%3A%226bb4001ccf2474747ed54ff6de03f02d8714141d635bebd7497ce959b037468b01112%22%2C%22xst%22%3A%2242394ab3995a5b2adde7ddcdd3a0d45965256cbf61a1e76a25f061e0f8c6c8c301112%22%7D%7D; lang=en-GB', 'x-security-token': '42394ab3995a5b2adde7ddcdd3a0d45965256cbf61a1e76a25f061e0f8c6c8c301112', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'}
xsec = d['x-security-token']
cst = [x.split("=")[1] for x in d['Cookie'].split(";") if "CST" in x][0]
```

---

```
42394ab3995a5b2adde7ddcdd3a0d45965256cbf61a1e76a25f061e0f8c6c8c301112
6bb4001ccf2474747ed54ff6de03f02d8714141d635bebd7497ce959b037468b01112
```

---

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/2e418e9d82)

Comment: Thanks, dunno why but im getting xsec = headers['x-security-token']
KeyError: 'x-security-token'

Comment: Check if the header exist and is lower case. It may be `X-SECURITY-TOKEN` - https://labs.ig.com/node/557

Comment: Thanks Pedro! As you can see from the har file the two rows are actually duplicated. if I replaced d with headers, it should still work??